# What is the purpose of erasing a type application to a term-application in parametric polymorphism?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, types-and-programming-languages, polymorphisms

From *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce

> **23 Polymorphism**
>
> **23.7 Erasure and Evaluation Order**
>
> in a full-blown programming language, which may include side-
>   eﬀecting features such as mutable reference cells or exceptions, the
>   type- erasure function needs to be deﬁned a little more delicately
>   than the full era- sure function in §23.6. For example, if we extend
>   System F with an exception- raising primitive error (§14.1), then the
>   term
>
> ```
> let f = (λX.error) in 0;
> ```
>
> evaluates to 0 because λX.error is a syntactic value and the error in
>   its body is never evaluated, while its erasure
>
> ```
> let f = error in 0;
> ```
>
> raises an exception when evaluated.
>
> What this shows is that type abstractions do play a signiﬁcant
>   semantic role, since they stop evaluation under a call-by-value
>   evaluation strategy and hence can postpone or prevent the evaluation
>   of side-eﬀecting primitives. We can repair this discrepancy by
>   introducing a new form of erasure appropriate for call-by-value
>   evaluation, in which we **erase a type abstraction to a term-abstraction**
>
> ```
> erasev (x) = x
> erasev (λx:T 1 . t 2 ) = λx. erasev (t 2 )
> erasev (t 1 t 2 ) = erasev (t 1 ) erasev (t 2 )
> erasev (λX. t 2 ) = λ_. erasev (t 2 )
> erasev (t 1 [T 2 ]) = erasev (t 1 ) dummyv
> ```
>
> where **`dummyv` is some arbitrary untyped value, such as `unit`**.

- Is the purpose of "erase a type abstraction to a term-abstraction" to prevent the body of a type abstraction from being evaluated?
- What is the purpose of erasing a type application to a term-application by adding `dummyv`?
- What is the evaluation rule for an application when the argument is `unit`?  (I can't find it in the section for type `Unit`.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Q1

- Is the purpose of "erase a type abstraction to a term-abstraction" to prevent the body of a type abstraction from being evaluated?

Yes.

> We can repair this discrepancy by introducing a new form of erasure appropriate for call-by-value evaluation, in which we erase a type abstraction to a term-abstraction

#### Q2

- What is the purpose of erasing a type application to a term-application by adding `dummyv`?

The erasure introduces a term-abstraction into a type-abstraction:

```
eraseᵥ(λX. t₂) = λ_. eraseᵥ(t₂)
```

So the erasure needs a term-application instead of a type-application. An argument of the term-application can be any untyped value because it will be discarded, so for example `unit`.

#### Q3

- What is the evaluation rule for an application when the argument is `unit`?  (I can't find it in the section for type `Unit`.)

The unit value `unit` is a value. Therefore we can use (E-APPABS) for an application.

```
(λx:T₁₁. t₁₂) v₂ ⟶ [x ↦ v₂] t₁₂    (E-APPABS)
```